Is it possible to create a fully dynamic webpage in wix editor, which can look something like this?
In Wix studio, can we create something like this? I can code it in react very well but unable to find a way to create it in wix.enter image description here
You can assume that images and layout are aligned. Image is just for representation. All of the data are dynamic from image link to title. Also, data will have a field type which will determine the background color.
I can fetch data from server and used repeater but it is very limited. Thus, I cant have what I want. Can velo help me? I have no idea about velo but I read their docs and saw use of velo many times.
